# How can I simulate a session login to test Rails controller methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to test some Rails controller actions that require a login.  Right now logging in is managed by setting the logged in user to `session[:user_id]` which all works as expected, but when I try to manually set it in my test (definitely open to a better way!) I get `NoMethodError: undefined method` session' for nil:NilClass` which is a really confusing error. message in the first place--I would have expected a NameError for an undefined variable.  I'd like to test both logged in and non logged in methods so I'm not sure if logging in during the setup phase is accurate (although I couldn't get it working anyway) but I'm open to any and all suggestions.  This is for a lesson teaching testing, so I want to keep it basic and *please* point out if I'm doing anything super wrong here before I teach it to impressionable youth.

```
require 'test_helper'

class TacosControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  setup do 
    @meat = tacos(:meat)
    @veggie = tacos(:veggie)
  end

  test "should redirect if not logged in" do 
    get new_taco_url
    assert_redirected_to login_path
  end

  test "should get new if logged in" do 
    session[:user_id] = users(:pat).id
    get new_taco_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create new taco" do 
    session[:user_id] = users(:pat).id
    assert_difference("Taco.count") do 
      post tacos_url, params: {taco: {name: "Yummy", price: 2.50}}
    end
  end


end
```

Comment: Are you able to pass the params like this: get new_taco_url, params: { session: { user_id: "your_data"  } }, that's the way you would pass a custom parameter to your controller using rspec, I notice that you're using a different test suite but it should be similar I think

Comment: Have you checked this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461101/accessing-session-in-integration-test