# Integration test, login with session is reset between http requests in the same test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, redis, minitest

I'm upgrading our application from rails 6.1.7 to 7.0.4 and have encountered an error where the session in the controller is reset after each http request, which did not happen before. **This only happens in the test env and not in dev env.**

When the user login and we have finished to authentication we set the following:

```
  def login_user!
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    .....
  end
```

When the user tries to visit another link we check the following

```
 def logged_in?
   session[:user_id].present?
 end
```

The test:

```
test 'updates locale' do
  post login_path, params: { email: user.email, password: user.password }, as: :json
  patch user_path(user), params: { user: { locale: 'en' } }, as: :json
end
```

Usually I use the first line `login_path` to set the session so that I can test other http requests as metnioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461101/accessing-session-in-integration-test). However it seems like the session is reset after each call in rails 7.
When I do the second request I get the following error: `<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x25648 not yet loaded>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future ref to others; This bug was due to that I use the gem `redis-session-store` which was not compatible with redis version 5 or higher and fakeredis version 0.7